# Does the cuda math function norm3df overflow?

Tags: c++, cuda, floating-point

I am working on an nbody simulator in cuda.  I want to use float types for the speed benefits but this is making my task difficult.  What I am worried about is say I have have a vector <10^20, 10^20, 10^20> and I want to compute its magnitude using the Pythagorean theorem.  I would have to square each of the components which would be 10^40 and in 32 bit this would just be infinity.  So even though the final result when I take the square root of the sum would be in range the intermediate step would overflow.  I came across the following function in the cuda math API.  norm3df(x, y, z).  Would this prevent the intermediate step overflow I am talking about?  Also I might need to use this function on the host as well as device.  Would the behavior be the same?

Comment: What would be stopping you from testing it out for yourself ? It's literally 20 lines of code...

Comment: The purpose of the standard C/C++ function `hypot()` as well as CUDA's additional functions `rhypot()`, `norm3d()`, and `rnorm3d()` is precisely to avoid the issue of overflow or underflow in the intermediate computation. As `rhypot()`, `norm3d()`, and `rnorm3d()` are not part of the standard C/C++ library, you won't be able to use them in host code. You may want to suggest to the vendor of your host compiler that these functions be added as proprietary extensions.

Comment: @njuffa that could probably serve as an answer.  FWIW I tested the proposed test case, using `norm3df()` and it gave the correct answer of `173205081561134792704.0`.  I'm curious as to why the function would be marked as `__host__ __device__` both in the header file as well as the documentation, if no host implementation exists.  I'm also curious about how `norm3d` would avoid intermediate overflow.  Does it use some kind of extension to `double` arithmetic?

Comment: I would assume it is implemented in hardware to avoid the overflow on the gpu.  I also want to know why it is marked __host__ because I can't link against it.

Comment: As previously discussed in another thread (here or in the NVIDIA forums) there seem to be some functions erroneously marked `__host__ __device__` in CUDA header files, possibly due to cut & paste. I haven't tried calling `norm3d()` in host code, but I don't think a host version exists. The technique for preventing intermediate overflow/underflow is to rescale operands as well as use clever transformation of the actual computation. No higher precision for intermediate results is required. For details, see the source code in the CUDA 6.5 version of `math_functions.h`, `math_functions_dbl_ptx3.h`

Comment: Here is the NIVIDIA forums thread I was thinking of (where we discussed a Bessel function provided by the CUDA math library erroneously being marked `__host__ device__`): https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/899238/cuda-programming-and-performance/undefined-reference-to-cyl_bessel_i0f-/

Comment: Thanks, I did try a host call to it, but it gives compile errors - exactly as you anticipated.  (It's always possible that I made a mistake, of course.)

Comment: A host implementation of `norm3D()` could only possibly exist in two places: (1) A header file that is included during host code compilation, or (2) an NVIDIA-provided host library linked in during the `nvcc` linking step. Grepping the CUDA 7.5 header files, it is easy to establish that no header file implementation exists, and examining the list of libraries that ship with CUDA 7.5 it is readily determined that no host math library is supplied (makes sense, as CUDA relies on the host toolchain for host code). Therefore, no host implementation of `norm3d()` exists.

Comment: As to why the header file and the documentation are both in error with regard to the `__host__` attribute for `norm3d()`, a look at the header file strongly suggests that the documentation is auto-generated from the header file, and the two are therefore guaranteed to be in sync (so both wrong in this case).

Answer (score 3):

The standard C++ math library contains a function `hypot()` for the computation of 2D norms *while avoiding premature underflow and overflow in intermediate computations*. Because 3D norms are also commonly encountered, the CUDA math library offers in addition an analogous function `norm3d()`. The description in the CUDA [math API documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/index.html) reads:

> Calculate the length of three dimensional vector p in euclidean space
>   without undue overflow or underflow

Further, the CUDA math library offers reciprocal norm functions `rhypot()` and `rnorm3d()` that are useful when normalizing 2D and 3D vectors, as they allow replacing an expensive division with a much cheaper multiplication.

As `norm3d()`, `rhypot()`, and `rnorm3d()` are not standard C++ math library functions, they cannot be used in the host portion of CUDA programs, as host code is processed by the host toolchain. NVIDIA provides math library support for the device. You may want to file an enhancement request with the vendor of your host toolchain to add these useful functions as proprietary extensions, and/or lobby the ISO C/C++ committees to have them added to future versions of the standard.

It has previously come to my attention that currently shipping CUDA header files seem to erroneously mark `normd3d()` and a few other CUDA-specific functions as `__host__ __device__`, although there is in fact no host implementation. This would appear to be a bug, likely caused by cut & past application of these attributes to the prototypes.

The norm and reciprocal norm functions do not require higher intermediate precision in their internal computation, meaning there is no negative performance impact on GPUs with low-throughput double precision. Instead, they use clever rearrangements of the mathematics, re-scaling of the operands, and use of FMA to achieve their goal. Not only do they prevent undue overflow and underflow, they should also be more accurate than the equivalent naive computation.

Up to and including CUDA version 6.5, implementation details of the CUDA math library were visible in the CUDA header files `math_functions.h` and `math_functions_dbl_ptx3.h`, so anybody who would like to get a better idea of the internal details of norm functions may want to look there.